# Find character selection after specified delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to (with a regular expression) find EVERYTHING specificed within my chararacer-set, after a delimiter (which is a colon).

Example:

```
Test3131:PythonBoolJava!Python
Overflow:PythonBoolFAKE!Python@021!
Overflo!w2:PythonBoolUnix-Python;?
Over3_flow:PythonBoolUnix^Python%
```

Desired output:

```
Test3131:PythonBoolJavaPython
Overflow:PythonBoolFAKEPython021
Overflo!w2:PythonBoolUnixPython
Over3_flow:PythonBoolUnixPython
```

So -
Ignore all data **before and including** the delimiter `:`
Search for all characters regardless of line position using the regex `[\$&\+,:;=\?@#\|'<>\.\^\*\(\)%!-]`

Upon when matched, I would choose to mark in my dataset manually.

What I have tried:
However, this was to no avail.

```
.*:.*[\$&\+,:;=\?@#\|'<>\.\^\*\(\)%!-]
```

However

Comment: You know, you could and should be using `.` instead of your crazy character sequence, right?

Comment: `.` matches every character, I only need to match symbols after the `:`

Comment: Ah, I get the question now. You have a good amount of symbols in your sequence that are metacharacters that need to be escaped with backslashes (almost all of them).

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't think about, that's an oversight from by behalf

Comment: I think this would be correct `[\$&\+,:;=\?@#\|'<>\.\^\*\(\)%!-]` I will update my post and hope I am correct.

Edit - I tested on Regex101 and my updated regex now seems to be correct.

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: @code: None of those characters have special meaning INSIDE a character class, so no need to escape those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If available, for example Python's PyPi's regex module, maybe:

```
(?::|\G(?!^)).*?\K[!#-.:-@^|]+
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yPAqF9/1). Notice how I condensed your character list down using the [ascii-table](https://www.asciitable.com/) to `[!#-.:-@^|]`. It still would capture all characters you have given.

- `(?:` - Open non-capture group;

  - `:` - Capture the first colon;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `\G(?!^)` - Asssert position at end of previous match but exclude start-line;
  - `)` - Close non-capture group;
- `.*?\K` - 0+ (Lazy) characters upto we reset starting point of reported match;
- `[!#-.:-@^|]+` - Any 1+ of given characters.

---

Another option, if available through JavaScript or Python's PyPi regex module, for example, is a zero-width lookbehind:

```
(?<=^[^:]*:.*?)[!#-.:-@^|]+
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1SLZmH/1)

- `(?<=^[^:]*:.*?)` - Positive lookbehind to check if there is a colon after start-line anchor and 0+ non-colon characters and any 0+ (lazy) characters right after that;
- `[!#-.:-@^|]+` - Any 1+ of given characters.

---

Code sample for Python:

```
import regex as re

l_in = ["Test3131:PythonBoolJavaPython", "Overflow:PythonBoolFAKEPython021", "Overflo!w2:PythonBoolUnixPython", "Over3_flow:PythonBoolUnixPython"]
l_out1 = [re.sub(r"(?::|\G(?!^)).*?\K[!#-.:-@^|]+", '', el) for el in l_in]
l_out2 = [re.sub(r"(?<=^[^:]*:.*?)[!#-.:-@^|]+", '', el) for el in l_in]

print(l_out1, l_out2)
```

Prints:

```
['Test3131:PythonBoolJavaPython',
 'Overflow:PythonBoolFAKEPython021',
 'Overflo!w2:PythonBoolUnixPython',
 'Over3_flow:PythonBoolUnixPython']
['Test3131:PythonBoolJavaPython',
 'Overflow:PythonBoolFAKEPython021',
 'Overflo!w2:PythonBoolUnixPython',
 'Over3_flow:PythonBoolUnixPython']
```